# How to kill any webserive call in salesforce.My Code has strucked

Tags: webservices

How to kill any webserive call in salesforce.
My code has given webservice call. Its uses *implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts*.

Now since morning call has strucked, it was showing previously in Apex queue jobs with error,: *storage DataStorge limits exceeded*.I have deleted most of the data. Also code is design in such a way that if first service is running on that object second attempt to run the service will be blocked till first call is complete. Now since 3 hours first service is going on and no logs. Even that is not in queue. How can i kill that process.

Comment: Search for `Scheduled Jobs` and select your job and delete it from there.

Comment: If you don't see log and its not there in queue, then how do you know its running?